# After upgrading to macOS Ventura, the tilde, pipe symbols and on Firefox fn+Opt+left-arrow) not working

Tags: terminal, keyboard, shortcut, iterm, ventura

I have upgraded my MacBook Pro 19 Intel to macOS Ventura.

Now, I have multiple issues with shortcuts and special symbols:

1. The tilde symbol doesn't display anymore on iTerm2 3.4.19: when I type <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, I get only the character "n" which appears
2. The pipe symbol: the same issue, when I type <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, I get only the character "L"
3. Finally, the shortcut on Firefox to get the home page with <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> doesn't work anymore.

Could anyone have these same issues or how to fix them? I have a French Azerty keyboard.

Comment: Does your keyboard work properly to type ~ and | in Apple apps like Safari and Mail?